# No Light in Object Mode

Tags: objects, 3d-view

Whenever I create a new Object all of them are black.
I tried to adjust in user preference, but it only useful for old object. New objects are still black.
Why?
[image: 3D view showing the black object]

Comment: can you upload your file?

Comment: Could it be that you turned two of your viewport lights down to black **or** disabled them **or** changed their direction in preferences? Looks like only the faces with inverted normals are lit. Try File > Load Factory Settings and add some objects there.